# What's Wrong With This Search Function?

Tags: python

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, _val):
        self._val = _val
        self._right = None
        self._left = None

    def search(self, val):
        if self._val == val:
            value = self._val
            return self
        if self._right is not None:
            right = self._right._val
            return self._right.search(val)
        if self._left is not None:
            left = self._left._val
            return self._left.search(val)
```

EXAMPLE CALL:

```
a = TreeNode(3)
b = TreeNode(2)
c = TreeNode(4)
a.search(4)
```

So this just defines a treenode class, and search is supposed to take a val and simply search for it when called on the ROOT of a binary tree. Upon running a testcase, it sometimes returns the correct node, sometimes it returns false when I know it's in the tree. Anyone know what might be causing this inconsistency?

Comment: If `self._right is not None`, flow will check there only and return. It will not go to `self._left`. That may explain the problem.

Comment: All the nodes a, b, c declared in the example are separate nodes with no linking. I think first you should join them with a._right = b , b._left = c as declared in your class.

Comment: It looks like your left nodes will be ignored if there's a right node (due to the return statement).

Answer (score 1):

`a.search(3)` will work, because a's value is 3. For anything else, it shouldn't because you never allowed the nodes to connect up. For each of these nodes, at least based on the code given, don't have left or right branches. They are all initialized with None and never set to anything else. You should state the root branch's left and right and then it should work.

For instance, your class should have this:

```
def setLeft(self, node):
   self._left = node
def setRight(self, node):
   self._right = node
```

Then use it as such:

```
a = TreeNode(3)
b = TreeNode(2)
c = TreeNode(4)
a.setLeft(b)
a.setRight(c)
a.search(4)
```

Of course, you should change it depending on how you wanted to structure the tree.

Answer (score 1):

## Problems

- If searching `self._right` returns `None` (the value isn’t anywhere on the right branch), your search will immediately `return`, never getting to traverse `self._left`. In fact, *as long as `self._right` exists (is not `None`), the `search` method never traverses `self._left`.*
- Also, you need to make sure to link up your nodes before running! For example, `a._left = c`.

## Solution

To fix this, I’d implement the `search` as follows:

```py
def search(self, val):
        if self._val = val:
            return self
        if self._right is not None:
            right = self._right.search(val)
            if right is not None:
                return right  # it’s okay to return now, we found something!
        if self._left is not None:  # if we’ve made it here, _right.search didn’t return
            return self._left.search(val)
        return None  # it’s good practice to explicitly return
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
if self._right is not None:
```

It will stop the search and return the result of search right if with self._right, and no more search for the left side.

Here, I revised code and do test.

```py
import random

class Node():

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value  = value
        self.left   = None
        self.right  = None

    def search(self, value):
        if self.value == value:
            return self
        result = None
        if self.left:
            result = self.left.search(value)
            if result:
                return result
        if self.right:
            result = self.right.search(value)
        return result

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Node value={self.value}>'

tree = {}
tree[0] = Node(0)

for i in range(1, 11):
    while True:
        parent = tree[random.choice(list(tree))]
        position = random.choice([0, 1])
        if (position==0 and parent.left) or (position==1 and parent.right):
            continue
        node = Node(i)
        tree[i] = node
        if position:
            parent.right = node
        else:
            parent.left = node
        break

root = tree[0]
for i in range(-5, 16):
    if i in tree:
        print(f'Value {i} found in {root.search(i)}')
    else:
        print(f'Value {i} not found')
```

```py
Value -5 not found
Value -4 not found
Value -3 not found
Value -2 not found
Value -1 not found
Value 0 found in <Node value=0>
Value 1 found in <Node value=1>
Value 2 found in <Node value=2>
Value 3 found in <Node value=3>
Value 4 found in <Node value=4>
Value 5 found in <Node value=5>
Value 6 found in <Node value=6>
Value 7 found in <Node value=7>
Value 8 found in <Node value=8>
Value 9 found in <Node value=9>
Value 10 found in <Node value=10>
Value 11 not found
Value 12 not found
Value 13 not found
Value 14 not found
Value 15 not found
```